# How to change navbar element background color using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change the element , and it just wouldnt work. Can anyone point out what am i doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#ffffff'});
 });
});
```

Comment: your code should work .. are you sure you include jquery before this code??

Comment: Review the browser console and include the errors that you find there.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Write this code after you have included jQuery.

Comment: @Noah Java console? `:P`

Comment: Thx guys i was just plain stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hover function in jquery needs two functions, the handleIn function as the first parameter and the handleOut function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
 },
 function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': 'white'});
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect using firebug, I guess you will that background is applied.

navbar element should have chlid "LI" element so you can add color to it by simply changing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar li").hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'background-color': '#ffffff'});
 });
});
```